# Need help to create formula/equation

Tags: probability, arithmetic

I am looking to try create a formula/equation(I am a novice). I'll use a fictitious example that has to do with basketball.  Assume there are 5 players that score in each game for each team.  Team A: C + PF1 + PF2 + G1 + G2 = Total Points scored ; Team B: C + PF1 + PF2 + G1 + G2 = Total Points scored.

What I have found is if I subtract the C points from the winning team that they still win X % of the time.  The actual number is 61.7% but that number is based on just 1800 games worth of research.

So, how would I write a formula/equation to fit my findings?

I know that this probably isn't a very difficult thing to do but I am not a mathematician and it isn't something that I can do.  I am a writer and really want to be able to show what my research shows using a mathematical formula.

PLEASE HELP!  TIA.

Comment: Can those voting the close please explain to the OP why they are doing so, and what the OP can do to improve their post?

Answer (score 1):

You successfully found the empirical percentage of a team that wins still be able to win without the center scoring. That is 
$$\frac{\text{number of times A wins and A still wins without center scoring} }{\text{number of times A wins}} \approx 61.7\%$$
for the $1800$ specific data that you took.

If you meant something else let me know.